# Subtracting rasters with different dimension, origin and extent in R

Tags: raster, r, extents

I have a large DEM raster from which I want to substract lots of smaller glacier rasters. Examples for the glacier rasters and a subset of the large DEM can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT

[image]

The smaller ones partially overlap, but only with their NA parts, so it should be possible to substract the glaciers from the DEM. When I just try substracting, I get the following:

```
filelocations <- list.files(pattern="*.tif", full.names=T) # many small rasters
HMA_DEM <- raster("/data/...") # one large raster

for (i in 1:length(filelocations)) {
   r = raster(filelocations[i]) 
   HMA_DEM <<- HMA_DEM - r
}

Error in setValues(r, values = methods::callGeneric(getValues(e1), getValues(e2))) : 
  length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In HMA_DEM - r :
  Raster objects have different extents. Result for their intersection is returned
2: In getValues(e1) - getValues(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

(Side note: I want to set HMA_DEM as global variable so that the next iteration takes the result of the previous one. Sure there are more elegant ways to do this?)

I am not sure how to address the error. The CRS is the same for all the rasters, extent and dimension differ, naturally.
My approach would be to fill every one of the smaller rasters with NAs until the extents are equal to the large `HMA_DEM`? How could I do that?
If there are other suggestions, I am open for them.

Comment: If you create a raster of zeroes the same as your DEM, then use `mosaic` to put your little glacier values into that, then you can subtract that from the DEM. But do your glacier rasters have the same `origin` as the DEM? In other words, do the cells line up? Can you give us a couple of examples?

Comment: Thanks! I provided some example data. Also, I used different projection methods (```gdalwrap``` and ```projectRaster```) for the large and small rasters, so maybe therefore the origin is different. Could I reproject the small ones with the projectRasterfunction providing the large raster as the ```to```-argument? Shouldn't the cells align then?