# Mosaicking many rasters with large empty raster in R

Tags: raster, r, mosaic

Following my previous question ([Subtracting rasters with different dimension, origin and extent in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/343496/145570)), I am trying to mosaic many small glacier rasters into one large empty raster which I can then subtract from my original raster (`HMA_DEM` = 38GB). Sample data @ https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT
Resolution and origin of the smaller ones and the large empty raster are the same. Some of the smaller rasters overlap with their NA-parts (for lack of a better word), so I'm using `fun=max` to overwrite the NA.

My code is this:

```
filelocations <- list.files(pattern="*.tif", full.names=T)
Albers_HMA <- crs("+proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
HMA_empty <- raster(extent(HMA_DEM), crs = Albers_HMA, res = res(HMA_DEM))

ras_mosaic <- mosaic(HMA_empty, raster(filelocations[1]), fun=max)
```

After running for a while, I get the following error:

```
Error in matrix(unlist(ini), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Warning messages:
1: In writeBin(v, x@file@con, size = x@file@dsize) :
  problem writing to connection
and so on
```

The warning messages seem to indicate that my disk space is full, but that is unlikely. Any ideas what to do?